# What is Java Error: 93: Reached end of file while parsing?

Tags: java, parsing

This may be a relatively simple question, but why is my program getting this error:Expression.java:93: error: reached end of file while parsing
   }

I have tried following multiple guides online, like opening and closing my classes correctly, but unfortunately I still seem to be getting this error.

Here is my code in case this helps:

```
public class Expression {
   private static final String SPACE = " ";
   private static final String PLUS = "+";
   private static final String MINUS = "-";


   public static int rank(String operator) {
      switch (operator) {
         case "^":       //5
            return 3;
         case "*":
         case "/":
            return 2;
         case PLUS:
         case MINUS:     //2
            return 1;
         default:
            return -1;
      }
   }

   public static boolean isOperator(String token) {     //4
      if (rank(token) > 0){
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public static int applyOperator(String operator,int op1,int op2){     //7
      switch (operator) {
         case PLUS:
            return op1+op2;
         case MINUS:
            return op1-op2;
         case "*":
            return op1*op2;
         case "/":
            return op1/op2;
         default:
            return -1;
      }
   }

   public static String toPostfix(String infixExpr) {
      StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
      Stack<String> operators = new ArrayStack<>();
      for (String token: infixExpr.split("\\s+")) {
         if (isOperator(token)) { // operator //4
            // pop equal or higher precedence
            while (!operators.isEmpty() &&
                  rank(operators.peek()) >= rank(token)) {
               output.append(operators.pop() + SPACE);
            }
            operators.push(token);
         } else {               // operand
            output.append(token + SPACE);
         }
      }
      while (!operators.isEmpty()) {
         output.append(operators.pop() + SPACE);
      }
      return output.toString();
   }

   public class PostFixTest {
    public static int evalPostfix(String infixExpr) {
      Stack <String> s = new ArrayStack<String>();
      String operand = null;
      for(int i = 0; i < infixExpr.length(); i++) {
         if (Character.isDigit(infixExpr.charAt(i)))
             s.push(infixExpr.charAt(i) + "");
         else {
             if (s.size() > 1) {
                int value1 = Integer.parseInt(s.pop());
                int value2 = Integer.parseInt(s.pop());
                s.push(applyOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i) + "", value1, value2) + "");
             }
         }
      }
      return s.pop();
      }
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(rank("/"));
      String infix = "a * b * c + d ^ e / f";
      System.out.println(toPostfix(infix));
      System.out.print("Using applyOperator method, 7 * 3 = ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("*", 3, 7));
      System.out.print("Using applyOperator method, 50 + 12 = ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("+", 50, 12));
   }
```

Comment: 93 is the line in your code where the error happens. Probably the end of your code. At that time the compiler expected more input, but did not get any. Double check your curly braces. Use an editor that can show matching braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are losing right `}` in your code last. like:

```
...
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(rank("/"));
      String infix = "a * b * c + d ^ e / f";
      System.out.println(toPostfix(infix));
      System.out.print("Using applyOperator method, 7 * 3 = ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("*", 3, 7));
      System.out.print("Using applyOperator method, 50 + 12 = ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("+", 50, 12));
   } 
} // you lost this bracket.
```